Re-render modal component onClick with random value parameters
i'm new to ReactJS. And I'm trying to create an app which displays a modal with different parameters. My problem is, I have a reusable modal component, but how do I achieve when pressing/clicking a button inside the modal will re-render the whole modal component with different results/value?
Here is my code:
Modal.js
import { useEffect, useRef, Fragment, Link, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { disableBodyScroll, enableBodyScroll } from "body-scroll-lock";
import airportData from '../airports.json';

export function Modal() {
    const modalRef = useRef();
    const { id } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const observerRefValue = modalRef.current;
        disableBodyScroll(observerRefValue);

        return () => {
            if (observerRefValue) {
                enableBodyScroll(observerRefValue);
            }
        };
    }, []);

    function setImageUrlLarge(url) {
        return {
            backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/large/${url}.jpg)`
        }
    }

    return (
        <div ref={modalRef} className="modal-wrapper">
            <div className="modal">
                <div className={`detail ${id} overlay`} style={setImageUrlLarge(id)}>
                    <a className='overlay' rel='noopener'></a>
                    <AirportDetails id={id} airportData={airportData} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

    function AirportDetails({id, airportData}) {
        const [data, setData] = useState(airportData);
        const [airportId, setAirportId] = useState(id);


        const airport = airportData.filter((airport) => airport.id.toLowerCase().includes(id.toLowerCase()))[0];

        const [description, setDescription] = useState(airport.description);

        const pattern = /\*([A-Za-z])\*/gi;
        const em = description.replace(pattern, '<em>$1</em>');  
    
        const currUrl = window.location.href;

        function capitalize(str) {
            return str.toUpperCase();
        }

        const share = (socialType) => e => {
            if (socialType == "twitter") {
                const text = `Making sense of those three-letter airport codes: ${capitalize(id)}`;
                const link = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=${currUrl}&text=${text}`;
                return link;
            }
            const link = `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?display=popup&href=${currUrl}${id}&redirect_uri=${currUrl}${id}`;
            return link;
        }

        function setTo(social) {
            if(social=="twitter") {
                return "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=$SHARE_URL&text=$TEXT";
            }  
            else {
                return "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=$SHARE_URL";
            }
        }

        return (
                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='detail-info'>
                        <h1>{airport.id}</h1>
                        <h2>{airport.name}</h2>
                        <h3><span className="local_name">{airport.local_name}</span></h3>
                        <h4>{airport.city}</h4>
                        <div className="description fl-edu">
                            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: em}}></p>
                        </div>
                        <a className="close-detail" role="button" onClick={() => navigate('/')}></a>
                        <a className="random" role="button" onClick={() => {randomAirport()}}>
                        Random Airport</a>
                         <div className="social">
                            <a role="button" className="twitter" href={setTo("twitter")} onClick={() => {share("twitter")}} target="_blank"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="social">
                            <a className="facebook" href={setTo("facebook")} onClick={() => {share("facebook")}} target='_blank'></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="photo-credit">
                        Photo by <a>{airport.imageCredit}</a>
                    </div>
                    <a className="back" role="button" onClick={() => navigate('/')}>Airport Codes PH</a>
                </div>
                
        )
    }

    function randomAirport() {
        const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * airportData.length);
        const airportRandData = airportData[rand];
        setReload(!reload);
        console.log(reload);
    }
}

What i'm achieving right now is to change the state of the modal every time when the button is clicked and randomizing the value of an object. I'm expecting to reload the modal component with a different value from the randomAirport function and passing the airportData back to the Modal component.

Do you want the airport data to be "random"... or based on the id prop?

hi, when clicking the "random" button, it should generate a random airport data(json) then pass it back to the component then reload the component with "that" random generated data.

The idea should be not to rerender the modal with different content, but to simply keep it open and make the component it renders re-render with it's own new state/content/etc.
Refactor your code to:

Separate & declare AirportDetails outside the Modal component so it's not redeclared each render cycle. This fixes a React anti-pattern. Remove the reload state, it's also an anti-pattern.
import { useEffect, useRef, Fragment, Link, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { disableBodyScroll, enableBodyScroll } from "body-scroll-lock";
import airportData from '../airports.json';

export function Modal() {
  const modalRef = useRef();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const observerRefValue = modalRef.current;
    disableBodyScroll(observerRefValue);

    return () => {
      if (observerRefValue) {
        enableBodyScroll(observerRefValue);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  function setImageUrlLarge(url) {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/large/${url}.jpg)`
    }
  }

  return (
    <div ref={modalRef} className="modal-wrapper">
      <div className="modal">
        <div className={`detail ${id} overlay`} style={setImageUrlLarge(id)}>
          <a className='overlay' rel='noopener'></a>
          <AirportDetails id={id} airportData={airportData} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


Update AirportDetails to initialize the data state to a random airport's data, and update the onClick handler to to select a random airport's data and enqueue a state update. Render all the airport details from the local data state.
function AirportDetails({ id, airportData }) {
  // Initialize data to specific airport by id,
  // otherwise select a random airport.
  const [data, setData] = useState(() => {
    const airport = airportData.find(
      (airport) => airport.id.toLowerCase().includes(id.toLowerCase())
    );

    return airport ? airport : randomAirport(airportData);
  });

  ...

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='detail-info'>
        <h1>{data.id}</h1>
        <h2>{data.name}</h2>
        <h3><span className="local_name">{data.local_name}</span></h3>
        <h4>{data.city}</h4>
        <div className="description fl-edu">
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: em}}></p>
        </div>
        <a
          className="random"
          role="button"
          onClick={() => {
            // Enqueue state update to new random airport data
            setData(randomAirport(airportData));
          }}
        >
          Random Airport
        </a>
        ...
      </div>
      <div className="photo-credit">
        Photo by <a>{data.imageCredit}</a>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

function randomAirport(airportData) {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * airportData.length);
  return airportData[rand];
}



Alternative
Since the id route path parameter and the airports.json data are used to compute the derived state in AirportDetails, an improvement I can suggest is to not copy any data into any local state (this is a bit of a React anti-pattern anyway) and directly compute the matching airport data based on the current id value, and to simply navigate to a new random airport id value.
Example:
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { disableBodyScroll, enableBodyScroll } from "body-scroll-lock";

export function Modal() {
  const modalRef = useRef();
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const observerRefValue = modalRef.current;
    disableBodyScroll(observerRefValue);

    return () => {
      if (observerRefValue) {
        enableBodyScroll(observerRefValue);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  function setImageUrlLarge(id) {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/large/${id}.jpg)`
    }
  }

  return (
    <div ref={modalRef} className="modal-wrapper">
      <div className="modal">
        <div className={`detail ${id} overlay`} style={setImageUrlLarge(id)}>
          <a className='overlay' rel='noopener'></a>
          <AirportDetails />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

import { useParams, useNavigate, generatePath } from "react-router-dom";
import airportData from '../airports.json';

function randomAirportId() {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * airportData.length);
  return airportData[rand].id;
}

function AirportDetails() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const airport = React.useMemo(() => {
    return airportData.find(
      (airport) => airport.id.toLowerCase().includes(id.toLowerCase())
    );
  }, [id]);

  ...

  if (!airport) {
    return null; // or navigate back, etc.
  }

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='detail-info'>
        <h1>{airport.id}</h1>
        <h2>{airport.name}</h2>
        <h3><span className="local_name">{airport.local_name}</span></h3>
        <h4>{data.city}</h4>
        <div className="description fl-edu">
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: em}}></p>
        </div>
        <a
          className="random"
          role="button"
          onClick={() => {
            navigate(
              generatePath("/airport/:id", { id: randomAirport()}
),
              { replace: true }
            );
          }}
        >
          Random Airport
        </a>
        ...
      </div>
      <div className="photo-credit">
        Photo by <a>{airport.imageCredit}</a>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}


Oh thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention that there is an initial data used by the modal component based on the parameter passed in the AirportDetails function. So, before initializing the state of the data to random, it should use first the data passed by the parent component.

@krxbnx Ah, I see, I'll update the lazy state initializer then to use that passed id prop. The code remains very similar.

Hello, thanks for the help. Again I tried to console.log the results from the randomAirport function, and yeah it's returning a random data. But the thing is, the modal is not updating its content based on the airport data being returned.

@krxbnx The modal doesn't need to, it just needs to render the AirportDetails component and pass the airport data to it and let it handle figuring out what content to render. You are rendering the content from the data state, right? Think you could create a running CodeSandbox demo of your code we could inspect live?

here is the app link: link and for the demo of code: link

@krxbnx There is an error in that sandbox installing dependencies, but there may be enough for me to make a minimal sandbox. I'll see what I can do.

oh I tried it again, and the only thing that is not updating when the random button is clicked is the background image since it's inside the Modal component that is dependent on the data from the AirportDetails

@krxbnx Ok, I've updated my answer to include an alternative that (IMO) is an improvement since it is just reactive to the id route path parameter and removes all the unnecessary local state and synchronization logic. Please take a look when you have time.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi @Drew, here is the updated link to my sandbox. Please let me know if you encountered any error again. I reverted my codes back to the first solution you provided.

I just included the other <div>s to the AirportDetails component, so it will also be updated when clicking the random button. Thanks for the help! However your second solution, didn't work for me as of the moment as the Modal component is not rendering after the random button is clicked.
